# MIPS Assembly Fahrenheit to Celsius converter failure

Tags: assembly, floating-point, mips

I am attempting to make a fahrenheit to celsius converter for the array values, but keep getting the wrong output (0.0 0.0 NaN Nan 0.0). I recognize that the issue lies in my conversion function (FtoC) but am not sure what piece is making it so incorrect. Any and all help is greatly appreciated

Here is what I have so far:
.data
List_F: .float 1.5, 0, -5, -12, 1
List_C: .float 0,0,0,0,0

size: .word 5

startString: .asciiz "Converting the following Fahrenheit to Celsius \n"
celsiusDisplay: .asciiz "\n\nTemperatures in Celsius \n"
newLine: .asciiz "\n"
.text
j main
FtoC:
add $sp, $sp, -4 #allocate space on stack
sw $ra, 0($sp)#save ra address to stack

```
li $t0, 0#acts as our 'i'
lw $t1, size#load the value 5 into $t1

li $t6, 32
mtc1 $t6, $f6 #put 32 into coproc 1 for calc


li $t7, 5
mtc1 $t7, $f2 #put five into coproc 1

li $t8, 9
mtc1 $t8, $f3#put nine into coproc1

div.s $f7,$f2, $f3 #get value of 5/9 in coproc
For:
    beq $t0, $t1, endFor #for (i < size
    sll $t3, $t0, 2
    lw $t9, List_F($t3)
    mtc1 $t9, $f0
    
    sub.s $f0, $f0,$f6
    mul.s $f4, $f0, $f7
    cvt.w.s $f5, $f4
    
    mfc1 $t5, $f5
    
    sw $t5, List_C($t3)
    
    add $t0, $t0,1#increment i
    j For#restart and retest loop conditions
endFor:
lw $ra, 0($sp)#recover ra address
add $sp, $sp, 4#deallocate memory

jr $ra#return back to step after function call
```

main:
li $t0, 0#acts as 'i'
lw $t1, size#get size
la $a0, startString
jal displayStartString

```
forFahrenheit:
beq $t0, $t1, endFahrDisplay
sll $t3, $t0, 2
lw $t4, List_F($t3)
mtc1 $t4, $f12

jal displayFahrenheit
la $a0, newLine
jal displayNewLine
add $t0, $t0,1
j forFahrenheit

endFahrDisplay:

jal FtoC

la $a0, celsiusDisplay
jal displayCelsiusString
li $t0, 0 #reset value of i

forCelsius:
beq $t0, $t1, endCelsiusDisplay
sll $t3, $t0, 2
lw $t4, List_C($t3)
mtc1 $t4, $f12

jal displayCelsius
add $t0, $t0,1

la $a0, newLine
jal displayNewLine

j forCelsius

endCelsiusDisplay:
la $a0, newLine
jal displayNewLine

jal endProgram
```

displayNewLine:
li $v0, 4
syscall
jr $ra

displayFahrenheit:
li $v0, 2
syscall

```
jr $ra
```

displayCelsius:
li $v0, 2      # syscall for printing float
syscall

```
jr $ra
```

displayCelsiusString:
li $v0, 4
syscall
jr $ra
displayStartString:
li $v0, 4
syscall

```
jr $ra
```

endProgram:
li $v0, 10
syscall
jr $ra

When I was fiddling with it, I ended up consistently getting this output:
0.8333334
-2.5E-44
-2.777778
-6.666667
0.5555556
This made me believe the issue was with my conversion, and upon watching it execute, whenever i converted from single precision to word, it always set the resulting value as 0, hence the output mentioned above. However, even with these nonzero values, they still didnt seem to be correct

Comment: -2.5E-44 sounds like a small integer bit-pattern got treated as a float32, e.g. perhaps forgetting an int-to-float conversion instruction somewhere.  (Perhaps before an FP negation or multiply with a negative number, since a small negative integer as a float bit-pattern would have an all-ones exponent field and represent a float32 that's a -NaN.)

Comment: thank you so much! That completely fixed it, I had made a mistake with the conversions.